# Filter/Block OpenVPN clients' access to a specific website

Tags: firewalls, access-control, openvpn

As stated in the title I would like to restrict VPN clients' access to specific websites.

More specifically, I push the route for 5 websites to the clients via the server config. However, I would like to block CLIENTS's access to one of these websites on an ad-hoc basis. In order to achieve this I understand that I have to edit the SERVER's iptables (directly or via ufw).

Unfortunately, I cannot manage to find the right way to do it!
The most promising rule I found is

`-A FORWARD -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -d X.X.X.X -j REJECT`

But that does not work. Maybe I am not putting the rule in the appropriate segment of ufw's before rules.

All other efforts (editing hosts, adding different rules in ufw, etc.) result in the server not being able to access the website, but with the clients unaffected by the rule!

Comment: What kind of access do you have to what machine?

Comment: Let me elaborate; I set up an OpenVPN server and routing the access of 5 websites via this network (i.e. if clients want to access one of these sites their traffic is directed via the VPN). The routing tables of the clients are being populated correctly. Now, if I want to block access to one of these 5 sites, what should I do? I thought that adding rules to the server's firewall (ufw/iptables) would do it, but no result.

Comment: Why.. don't you... remove ... this one website from however you setup this routing?

Comment: It normally does. If you have iptables on your openvpn server setup correctly you can use it. Common mistakes include: not having set the correct input device, output device or e.g. source IP. All traffic caused by openvpn is available to iptables (that's a very generalized statement but I have never seen otherwise). Maybe you got in trouble with NAT?

Comment: @ Tom K.: If I do that I lose the opportunity of controlling user's access to it!

Comment: @ Ben: I know! The issue is that I don't seem to enter the correct rule. It is also possible that I may have the correct rule (e.g. -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -d X.X.X.X -j REJECT) but I do not enter it in the correct segment of ufw's before.rules. That's why I am asking for someone to help me. My nat is a typical nat for OpenVPN (*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o INTERFACE -j MASQUERADE).

Comment: @skifast please edit your question to include all these details that you have provided

Comment: Why not change the route to a black hole using the process you used to route the site in the first place?

Comment: @schroeder: like 127.0.0.0? The drawback of this solution, should it work, is that I will have restart the OpenVPN server process, meaning that all users will be disconnected momentarily. Also this change will show up on their routing table. I need something solely on the server side.

Comment: You should probably edit your question so that it reflects your situation as accurately as possible and then it should be migrated to Serverfault.

Comment: @Tom K.: I don't believe that it can get more detailed than that. How can I migrate it to Serverfault?

Comment: @skifast That is happening after it gets a number of migration votes or a mod steps in. Not much you can do but wait.